# How to pass parameters to ListView?

Tags: django

How to pass variables (*min_amount* and *max_amount*) from `done()` to `SearchAdvertResultView(ListView)`?

---

**done() method of some object**:

```
def done(self)
    ...
    min_amount = 100
    max_amount = 500
    return redirect(reverse('board:search-result'))
```

**urls.py**:

```
...
url(r'^results$',
    SearchAdvertResultView.as_view(),
    name='search-result',
    ),
...
```

**views.py**:

```
...
class SearchAdvertResultView(ListView):
    template_name = "board/search_results.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        return Adverts.objects.filter(amount__range=(min_amount, max_amount))
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def done(self)
    ...
    min_amount = 100
    max_amount = 500
    urlparams = '?min_amount=%s&max_amount=%s' % (min_amount, max_amount)
    return redirect(reverse('board:search-result')+urlparams)

class SearchAdvertResultView(ListView):
    template_name = "board/search_results.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        min_amount = self.request.GET.get('min_amount')
        max_amount = self.request.GET.get('max_amount')
        return Adverts.objects.filter(amount__range=(min_amount, max_amount))
```